# How to get the most accumulated hours?

Tags: sql, correlated-subquery

List the name of employee and his/her division name, who have MOST accumulated hours working on project. Also list his/her accumulated hours.

```
SELECT e.name, e.empid, e.did,  e_hrs.emphours
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN
(select empid, sum(hours) as emphours
from workon
group by empid) e_hrs
ON e.empid= e_hrs.empid
```

How would I do the most accumulated hours?

Comment: Can't you just order by the total hours in descending order and limit the result to one row?

Answer (score 1):

by adding order by and you can limit to 1:

```
SELECT e.name, e.empid, e.did,  e_hrs.emphours
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN
(select empid, sum(hours) as emphours
from workon
group by empid) e_hrs
ON e.empid= e_hrs.empid
Order by e_hrs.emphours desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: How would I add the division name?

Comment: @liline add it to your select list . you have not provided any information and even its not part of your question